# MATLAB - Data is lost when closing the FOR loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm having trouble with a loop that counts the white pixels in a
piece of an image, and stores the total white pixels and the y and x
position of that piece in the image, each on its own array.

When I print the values inside the loop it works just fine, but right
after the loop the 3 arrays are filled with zeros.

Can anyone help?

Cod:

```
y = zeros(altura*largura);
x = zeros(altura*largura);
v = zeros(altura*largura);


for j=0:altura-1
    for k=0:largura-1

        pedaco = f8(j*40+1 : j*40+40, k*40+1 : k*40+40); %binary piece
        pedac = im2uint8(pedaco);
        totalBrancos = sum(sum(pedac)); %sum white pixels

        pos = altura*j+k+1;

        y(pos) = j;
        x(pos) = k;
        v(pos) = totalBrancos;

        disp(y(pos)); %works
        disp(x(pos)); %works
        disp(v(pos)); %works

    end
end  

disp(y); %all zeros
disp(x); %all zeros
disp(v); %all zeros
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's all zeroes? If the matrices are large, maybe you're only seeing part of them displayed in the Command Window. Try `imagesc(y);` for each matrix instead.

Comment: This should work as expected, please provide a [mcve], i.e. define all variables.

Comment: Probably should index from 1 instead of 0 in true matlab style. It seems that you're coming from another programming language.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? I copied and pasted this into R2012b, changed a few of the functions and assigned values to unknowns, and it all works as expected - it just looks odd because all of the values are in the left-hand column of the final matrix due to how you've created them and indexed them.

Answer (score 0):

Your zeros calls are creating a (altura*largura) by (altura*largura) matrix, which I don't think is what you intended as you are saving data into by calculating a position

If that's the case, try

```
y = zeros(1, altura*largura);
x = zeros(1, altura*largura);
v = zeros(1, altura*largura);
```

It is possible to use a single index into a multi-index matrix, however your `pos` calculation is not correct for doing that.

Comment: Note that it is possible to access elements elements in a multi dimensional array using linear indexing.